# When using Spring Rest Template how to write out non convertable message body

Tags: java, spring, rest

I'm using Spring Rest Template and I send DidCheckRequest and try to convert the result to DidCheckResponse (content is not important) like this:

```
    final HttpEntity<DidCheckRequest> requestEntity = getDidCheckRequestEntity(didName); //details not important
    //restTemplate is an instance of org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate
    final ResponseEntity<DidCheckResponse> responseEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity(catalogUrl, requestEntity, DidCheckResponse.class);
```

However, when something goes wrong, like I have some bad header or there is an authentication failure, I get other than 200 HTTP Status and the body is can not be converted to DidCheckResponse and I get the `org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException`, which tells me, that I have no converter for the actual result. I would like to get the returned body, which I would like to write out. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

When something is wrong, it should not be 200 actually. 200 status code is only meant when you receive a successful response.

For other than 200, have a different Response class, a generic error response class to handle the conversion problem.

You can refer below.
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-template-error-handling